# Flink Scala - Comparison method violates its general contract

Tags: java, scala, flink-streaming

I am writing a project in Flink that involves streaming a set of query points over batched data and performing a full sequential scan to find the nearest neighbors. What should be a simple sort operation on a single Float value throws a violation of the general contract error. The main method is defined as:

```
object StreamingDeCP{
  var points: Vector[Point] = _

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val queryPointsVec: Vector[Point] = ... // Read from file
    val pointsVec: Vector[Point] = ...      // Read from file

    val streamEnv: StreamExecutionEnvironment = 
                   StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val queryPoints = streamEnv.fromCollection(queryPointsVec)

    points = pointsVec
    queryPoints.map(new StreamingSequentialScan)

    streamEnv.execute("StreamingDeCP")
  }

  final class StreamingSequentialScan 
                    extends MapFunction[Point, (Point, Vector[Point])] {

    def map(queryPoint: Point): (Point, Vector[Point]) = {
      val nn = points
                .map{ _.eucDist(queryPoint) }
                .sorted

      (queryPoint, nn)
    }
  }
}
```

The `Point` class and companion object are:

```
case class Point(pointID: Long,
                 descriptor: Vector[Float]) extends Serializable {
  var distance: Float = Float.MaxValue

  def eucDist(that: Point): Point = {
    // Simple arithmetic to calculate and set the distance variable
  }
}

object Point{
  implicit def orderByDistance[A <: Point]: Ordering[A] =
    Ordering.by(_.distance)
}
```

Here are some notes about the things I have tried, in order to pinpoint the cause:

- Asserted all `distance` values are between Float.MaxValue and Float.MinValue and no negative-zero values exist
- Asserted that there are no duplicate `distance` variables within the same sort operation (my use case allows for this, but I thought I would check it just in case)
- Converted the Float to an Integer value and sorting on those values instead
- Added an explicit ordering on `Point` instead of using implicits
- Sorting on the unique `pointID` instead of `distance`, which *works* but is useless for the context of this problem.

I also noted, that executing the same code does not always reproduce the error reliably. I am reading the `Vector[Points]` in a fully deterministic way, so the only possibly cause for this behavior must be the Flink scheduler or some stateful computation in the sorting method.

Other posts on the same topic seem to involve a missed scenario in the custom comparator, but this should be a simple sort operation on a single Float value, so I have no idea about what could cause the issue.

Comment: Why do you have any `var`s in a case class, why does `eucDist` return a `Point` instead of a scalar value, and why don't you just `.sortBy(_.eucDist(queryPoint))`?

Comment: The distance is not known when a Point instance is created, I need to retain the pointID information and I do not know the semantic difference between the `.sorted` pipeline I wrote, and the `.sortBy` method you propose.

Comment: The semantic difference is that your `.map{ _.eucDist(queryPoint) }` seems to mutate the variables `distance` inside `Point`, whereas the `sortBy` proposal would have no side-effects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Flink, but I don't have any reason to assume that it will execute every [embarrassingly parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embarrassingly_parallel) `MapFunction` task in a sequential single-threaded manner.

Since your `Point` contains `var`s, and those `var`s are mutated in the `map` method of the `MapFunction`, the code must fail with a *"Comparison method violates its general contract"*-exception whenever the `MapFunction` is executed with parallelism `!= 1`.

To avoid any side effects inside the `map` function, you could modify the code as follows:

- Remove any `var`s from `main`, make `points` an immutable `val`.
- Remove any kind of `var`s from `Point`
- Implement the method

  ```
  def eucDist(other: Point): Double
  ```

  that simply computes the distance to another point (without mutating anything).
- Use `sortBy`:

  ```
  val nn = points.sortBy(_.eucDist(queryPoint))
  ```

Alternatively, if you want to avoid recomputing the Euclidean distance multiple times during sorting, precompute the distances once, sort, and then throw the distances away:

```
val nn = points.map(p => (p, p.eucDist(queryPoint))).sortBy(_._2).map(_._1)
```